# Multiprocess message queue not receiving messages

Tags: python, multiprocess

I have a script that creates a class and try's to launch an object of that class in a separate process;

```
class Task():
  def __init__(self, messageQueue):
    self.messageQueue = messageQueue

  def run(self):
    startTime = time.time()
    while time.time() -startTime < 60:
      try:
        message = self.messageQueue.get_nowait()
        print message
        self.messageQueue.task_done()
      except Queue.Empty:
        print "No messages"
      time.sleep(1)

def test(messageQueue):
  task = Task(messageQueue)
  task.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  messageQueue = Queue.Queue()
  p = Process(target=test, args=(messageQueue,))
  p.start()
  time.sleep(5)
  messageQueue.put("hello")
```

Instead of seeing the message "hello" printed out after 5 seconds, I just get a continuous stream of "No messages". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [`Queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-queue), which only handles multiple threads within the same process, not multiple processes.

The `multiprocessing` module comes with its own replacement, [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), which provides the same functionality, but works with *both* threads and processes.

See [Pipes and Queues](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) in the `multiprocessing` doc for more details—but you probably don't need any more details; the `multiprocessing.Queue` is meant to be as close to a multi-process clone of `Queue.Queue` as possible.

---

If you want to understand the under-the-covers difference:

A `Queue.Queue` is a deque with condition variables wrapped around it. It relies on the fact that code running in the same interpreter can access the same objects to share the deque, and uses the condition variables to protect the deque from races as well as for signaling.

A `multiprocessing.Queue` is a more complicated thing that pickles objects and passes them over a pipe between the processes. Races aren't a problem, but signaling still is, so it also has the equivalent of condition variables, but obviously not the ones from `threading`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed something so simple. Thanks for pointing this out